# POST (OL3-->Geoserver 2.8.1-->PostGIS 2.2)

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wfs, post

I have a problem with post. Here is code OL3. (multi platform hybrid app - cordova)

```
var point = new ol.geom.Point([18.25, 49.83]);    
var feature = new ol.Feature({
     geometry: point
});

feature.setGeometryName('the_geom');
feature.set("popis", "abcd");
feature.setId("body.8");

var format = new ol.format.WFS({
    featureNS: "moj",
    featureType: "body"
});
    var node = format.writeTransaction([feature], null, null, {
        gmlOptions: { srsName: "EPSG:4326" },
        featureNS: "moj",
        featureType: "body"
    });
    console.log("node: "+node)
    console.log("xml:" + new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node));

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
        data: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node),

       contentType: 'text/xml',
       success: function (data) {
           var result = format.readTransactionResponse(data);
           console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            var errorMsg = e ? (e.status + ' ' + e.statusText) : "";
            console.log('Error saving this feature to GeoServer.<br><br>'
                + errorMsg);
        }/*,
        context: this*/
    });
```

And here is Transaction file

```
xml:<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
<Insert><body xmlns="moj" fid="body.8"><geometry><Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:4326"><pos>49.83 18.25</pos></Point></geometry><popis>abcd</popis></body></Insert></Transaction>
```

And here is ERROR from Geoserver LOG

```
    01 dec 22:18:22 ERROR [geoserver.ows] -
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Could not determine geoserver request f
rom http request org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter$AdvancedDispatchH
ttpRequest@5eafc7c6
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:629)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:26
5)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(
AbstractController.java:153)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.ha
ndle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Dispatch
erServlet.java:923)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Dispatche
rServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Frame
workServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServ
let.java:789)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487
)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1093)
        at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocals
CleanupFilter.java:28)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1084)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDel
egatingFilter.java:75)
        at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java
:71)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDel
egatingFilter.java:71)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatin
gFilter.java:46)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1084)
        at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispat
chFilter.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1084)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterCh
ain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInter
ceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInter
ceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterCh
ain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoSe
rverCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterCh
ain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.do
Filter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterCh
ain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoSe
rverCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.
doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterCh
ain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticati
onFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterCh
ain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoSe
rverCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFi
lter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterCh
ain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFi
lter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilt
er$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterCh
ain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoSe
rverCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChai
nProxy.java:173)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(Geo
ServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(D
elegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(Delegat
ingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1084)
        at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:87)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1084)
        at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1084)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.
java:48)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1084)
        at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:4
4)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1084)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterIntern
al(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:76)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1084)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:3
60)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.jav
a:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:1
81)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:7
26)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)

        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHand
lerCollection.java:206)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.
java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:1
52)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:50
5)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpCo
nnection.java:828)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.ja
va:395)
        at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool
.java:450)
```

IDEA?